# TensorFlow reinforcement learning softmax layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, softmax

I have a problem with TensorFlow Code. Here is a piece of code that I used in my previous environment - Cart-pole problem

```
initializer = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer()

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_inputs])

hidden = tf.layers.dense(X, n_hidden, activation=tf.nn.elu, kernel_initializer=initializer)
logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden, n_outputs)
outputs = tf.nn.sigmoid(logits)  

p_left_and_right = tf.concat(axis=1, values=[outputs, 1 - outputs])
action = tf.multinomial(tf.log(p_left_and_right), num_samples=1)

y = 1. - tf.to_float(action)

cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(cross_entropy)
```

There was two possible discrete decisions (right and left move).

I had decision given by sigmoid layer, which later was randomly selected with probabilities given by that layer.

Now I have environment with three discrete possible decisions, so I tried with softmax layer and it not work. When I start TensorFlow session.
The code is like that:

```
initializer = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer()

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_inputs])

hidden = tf.layers.dense(X, n_hidden, activation=tf.nn.elu, kernel_initializer=initializer)

logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden, n_outputs)

outputs = tf.nn.softmax(logits)  

p_left_and_right = tf.concat(axis=3, values=[outputs])
action = tf.multinomial(tf.log(p_left_and_right), num_samples=1)

y = 1. - tf.to_float(action)
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=y, logits=logits)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(cross_entropy)
```

How should I change or improve it, to achieve suitable result and correct/better TensorFlow's code

Comment: Just skip the `p_left_and_right` definition and use `logits` directly as the multinomial logits. And for `y`, you probably just want to use `action`. In short, remove the 2-class specific hacks and you're good to go.

Comment: I change it like that: 

| hidden = tf.layers.dense(X, n_hidden, activation=tf.nn.elu, kernel_initializer=initializer) 

| logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden, n_outputs) 
| action = tf.multinomial(tf.log(logits),

num_samples=1)
| y = 1. - tf.to_float(action)
| cross_entropy =
tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=y, logits=logits) 
But it still not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution of problem is changing the cross entropy function. I changed it to sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits , which doesn't need labels in one hot encoding format.

```
initializer = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer()

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_inputs])

hidden = tf.layers.dense(X, n_hidden, activation=tf.nn.elu, kernel_initializer=initializer)

logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden, n_outputs)

action = tf.multinomial(logits, num_samples=1)


cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels= action[0], logits=logits)
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to run this myself, but my guess would be to drop the hacks that were introduced to map the Bernouli case to the more general Categorical case.

To be more specific, I'd try to do this:

```py
initializer = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer()

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_inputs])

hidden = tf.layers.dense(X, n_hidden, activation=tf.nn.elu, kernel_initializer=initializer)

logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden, n_outputs)

action = tf.multinomial(logits, num_samples=1)

cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=action, logits=logits)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(cross_entropy)
```

(I assume you use these grads to build a proper feedback signal that also involves some returns/advantages)

Comment: With this I have an error : F ./tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:781] Check failed: NDIMS == new_sizes.size() (2 vs. 1)
Aborted (core dumped)